# Bathymetry dataset of Italy with 3 arc-seconds resolution or better

Tags: data, bathymetry, italy

I am looking for a dataset of bathymetry data of Italy. I shall use it in an application for collision avoidance of vessels coming into the port.

I need to know how deep the sea bottom is at each point, and that's why data should be as precise and graded as possible. So I am considering only data with greater resolution than 3 arc-seconds.

Can someone help me to find open source or not too expensive data within these constraints?

Comment: So depth data for Ionian, Adriactic & Mediterranean Seas?

Comment: http://portal.emodnet-hydrography.eu/download-bathymetry (0.25 arc-sec)

Comment: No Mapperz, that's not the right resolution:
"The EMODnet digital terrain model (DTM), on which all products in this portal are based, has been created at a resolution of 0.25 arc-minutes"

Answer (score 1):

I only know the global SRTM plus bathymetry with 1km grid size. Furthermore you might try here: http://www.marine-geo.org/portals/gmrt/